# Google Maps Android API v2: how can i set marker over "blue dot" (z order)

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am writing an app using Google Maps Android v2 SDK. When I place a marker on the map at my location, it always appears underneath the default "blue dot" from the built-in my location layer. This does not happen when using the Google Maps SDK for iOS. How can I make my own marker be drawn on top of the blue dot?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can add marker on your location like this :

```
           LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), 
         mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);

              markerOptions.title("You");
               mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
               mCurrLocationMarker.setVisible(true);
```

Please search google or stackoverflow first always..Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it not my issue. I added a marker but it below "blue dot",  want it above

Comment: @3iAndroid yes this is exactly your issue according to your question. After you have marker on the blue dot you will have to write additional code to keep it moving with the blue dot.

Comment: Changing the zIndex does not appear to fix the issue described in the question. The blue dot is still drawn on top of the custom marker.

Answer (score -2):

markers have a `zIndex()` value which you can use

Comment: do you need that blue dot?

Comment: yeah, i need this

Comment: @masoudvali I've set  marker.zIndex=10.0f but z index is not changing. Is there any other property I need to change?

Comment: Changing the zIndex does not appear to fix the issue described in the question.